# Health rated data and information in Ghana and Kenya needed

Tags: data-request, medical

I am a student from georgetown university. I am doing a research on health instruments sterilization in Ghana and Kenya. I am wondering if any one can help me find the data or information to following answers:

1. What type of autoclaves (brand name)  are hospitals in Kenya and Ghana using?
2. What is the average cost of purchasing these autoclaves?
3. How frequently is the autoclave used in a day?
4. How long is one cycle (two hours, eight hours, etc)? How much is the electricity consumption per cycle?
5. How much water is needed per cycle?
6. Is there a backup generator? How much does it cost? How often does it operate?
7. How is maintenance support provided for autoclaves in the facility? How much does this support cost? How often is maintenance required?
8. If a facility does not use an autoclave, what are they using for sterilization?

If you know where to find these data or know someone who may know these data, please feel free to contact me.

Thank you very much! !